# get value between [ ] and value outside of [ ]through regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, string, plsql

I have strings like:

```
var = This a string, [This is another string]
```

I would like to have them broken into something like this in PLSQL

```
var1 = This is string
var2 = This is another string
```

The comma should not be included if it is like:

```
, [
```

Basically this decides if there is another string.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`SUBSTR`](http://psoug.org/reference/substr_instr.html) and [`INSTR`](http://psoug.org/reference/substr_instr.html) to split the string. For example, to obtain the first string, you can use something along these lines:

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(var, 1, INSTR(var, ',') - 1), var)
FROM dual;
```

That is, find the index of the separator (`INSTR(var, ',')`), and then use `SUBSTR` to capture everything up to that index. Same applies to the second string.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, and what if there is no "second string"? then the result would be empty.

Comment: Correct, you could wrap that expression with `NVL`, and use the original string in that case. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, that works.
However, to get second string, I used the following:

select nvl(substr(var instr(var, '[') +1, instr(var, ']') -1), var) FROM dual

Now the problem is that I get [ character at the last of the second string

Answer (score 2):

I think this will give what you want, though I'm not 100% clear on your parsing requirements.

```
var1 := regexp_replace( var, '^([^[,]*).*$', '\1')
var2 := regexp_replace( var, '^[^[]*(\[([^]]*)\])?.*$', '\2')
```

Here is a [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/2403) that tests the regex functions.

I'm also not sure about performance of a regex solution vs. other methods.